# How can you execute Gitlab stages conditionally?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

There are 3 stages - build, test and deploy in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

A nightly regression test stage needs to be run nightly.

Here's the relevant `.gitlab-ci.yml` code:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd ./some-dir
    - build-script.sh
  except:
  - tags

#Run this only when say variable 'NIGHTLY_TEST == True'. But HOW?
nightly_regression_test_project:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd ./some-dir
    - execute test-script
```

Tagging daily to only run the `test` stage is not preferable.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503715/3439096) an answer with screenshots and example. Hope that helps

Comment: This is a question about pipeline "scheduling", not really about pipeline stage "conditional " execution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for this now, gitlab has now implemented a scheduled build feature with variable overwriting (incredibly handy).  Documentation found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html).

For anyone interested in the instructions for this feature when this answer was given, here it goes:

**Using Pipeline Schedules**

In order to schedule a pipeline:

1. Navigate to your project's **Pipelines -> Schedules** and click the **New Schedule** button.
2. Fill in the form
3. Hit **Save pipeline schedule** for the changes to take effect.

My favorite feature of this is the scheduled pipeline variables.

The variables documentation can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/), but the most useful information for me was the priority, which I will retype here:

**Priority of Variables**

The variables can be overwritten and they take precedence over each other in this order:

1. Trigger variables or scheduled pipeline variables (take precedence over all)
2. Project-level secret variables or protected secret variables
3. Group-level secret variables or protected secret variables
4. YAML-defined job-level variables
5. YAML-defined global variables
6. Deployment variables
7. Predefined variables (are the lowest in the chain)

Hope this helps.  I'm delighted that they added this feature.

Comment: If you can actually put something together in answer itself, it would be handy for reference then going to the doc

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I was worried that the instructions would change in the next month or so.  I'll go back and add instructions for the current method, and hope that they don't change it :)

Comment: The documentation is not helpful. It shows how to set a variable and it shows how to use `only` and `except` for schedules, but it doesn't show how to use `only` and `except` WITH variables. What syntax should be used?

Answer (score 51):

`except` and `only` can specify variables that will trigger them.

You can use the following in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
build1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Only when NIGHTLY_TEST is false"
  except:
    variables:
      - $NIGHTLY_TEST 
    
test1:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo "Only when NIGHTLY_TEST is true"
  only:
    variables:
      - $NIGHTLY_TEST
```

Comment: Note: you can't just leave the variable unset. it must have the value `true` (all lowercase)

Comment: what are the possible ways to define NIGHTLY_TEST variable?

Comment: @DiegoMarin One way would be from Settings > CI / CD > Variables. Another would be using Schedules (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503715/3498950)

Answer (score 18):

There's not currently a way to run a job that depends on environment variables (you can always open a feature request!). You could use a simple Bash command to immediately exit if the environment variable doesn't exist, though.

Something like:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd ./some-dir
    - build-script.sh
  except:
  - tags

# Run this only when NIGHTLY_TEST environment variable exists.
nightly_regression_test_project:
  stage: test
  script:
    - [ -z "$NIGHTLY_TEST" ] && exit 1;
    - cd ./some-dir
    - execute test-script
```

If the variable doesn't exist the tests that follow it won't run. Otherwise, they will.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you don't want the `nightly_regression_test_project` job failing to fail the whole pipeline, you can use `exit 0` instead of `exit 1`: the job will terminate, but the pipeline will continue

Comment: need to quote "[ -z '$NIGHTLY_TEST' ] && exit 1;"

Comment: I am getting "bad indentation of a sequence entry" error in gitlab editor

Answer (score 7):

Select CI/CD -> Schedules on the left frame of your project:

[image]

Create a new Schedule:

[image]

Add your `NIGHTLY_TEST` variable and set it to `True`:

[image]

Add the `only` and `variables` section to your `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
    nightly_regression_test_project:
      stage: test
      script:
        - cd ./some-dir
        - execute test-script
      only:
        variables:
          - $NIGHTLY_TEST == "True"
```

-- UPDATE --
Using the new [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#common-if-clauses-for-workflowrules) based logic, you can do this instead:

```yaml
    nightly_regression_test_project:
      stage: test
      script:
        - cd ./some-dir
        - execute test-script
      rules:
        - if: $NIGHTLY_TEST == "True"
          when: always
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below rule on the jobs which you don't need to run on schedule.

```
    rules:
     - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score -5):

I just implemented this "feature" by following the example found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/)
Use crontab and curl(I use Linux, because why not?) to set off a trigger to run your nightly tests.

```
30 0 * * * curl --request POST --form token=TOKEN --form ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/9/trigger/builds
```